# Using EasyPHP Webserver

Tags: java, php, android

I'm not sure how one goes about using EasyPHP Webserver. Looking around the internet there doesn't seem to be a lot of materials on the matter. Whenever I try to run a php file from the www folder, a new blank tab appears without output from script code (Simple hello world echo). I'm not sure what the problem could be. My Http server and db server is running.

I'm also not sure if EasyPHP devserver is capable of going online. I'm currently in the middle of building an application that requires information to be sent to the server. My android application has been having trouble connecting to the EasyPHP devserver. Will I have more success with EasyPHP Webserver than I will with Devserver?

Comment: I would strongly recommend using a better Web Server. As such as **Lighttpd** or **Apache**. There will be many more resources available to help you configure and get it setup.

Comment: Which service are you trying to access with your application? A webserver or a database server?

Comment: @Lonkey, Webserver

Answer (score 0):

If you can make a success request using browser, then I think there will be no problem in Android.

Try to debug your webservice using tools like RestClient or PostManager.

Also, when connecting to webservice from Android application, I suggest using third party library like retrofit2. It's quite simple and we will never bothering with parsing json anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the devserver running, you simply have to right click on the tray icon and select "Open Dashboard". There you can enable and set up all the services such as modules that you need. **Please note that EasyPHP devserver is not designed to be used for a production server!**

**For performance and security reasons**, I do strongly recommend to use Apache or nginx with the current stables of PHP 7.0.x and MySQL. If you need some help with that, feel free to ask me in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

EasyPHP Webserver or Devserver are not a web server. It is a manager that installs Apache, PHP, MySQL, and other utilities, just like WAMP or XAMPP.

Just be sure to start the application that loads the Apache server before doing anything. 
about your Android device connecting with the server, I'm not sure how that could be done, I have been more lucky using node, gulp and some scripts to generate a web server that is accessible to my devices in my local network.